# She gets angry every time I mention it. (Where is "when"?)

Tags: phrase-usage

Could you say, please, why "when" isn't necessary here before "I"? Or it can be here? What grammar rule is it?

> She gets angry every time I mention it.

Comment: Sergey, It is not a good idea to immediately accept the first answer to a question: other people may be able to supply a clearer or more detailed answer to your question, and they may decide not to bother if you have already accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need "when" because the phrase "every time" establishes *when* it happens - it happens *every time*.

The two could be interchangeable:

- She gets angry **every time** I mention it.
- She gets angry **when** I mention it.

Another possibility would be:

- She gets angry **whenever** I mention it.

Comment: As I understood your message, it is opposite to JavaLatte, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

"She gets angry every time" and "I mention it" are two independent clauses that are separated by... nothing: they are called [contact clauses](https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/contact_clause.htm). Contact clauses occur when a relative pronoun is omitted. In your sentence, the relative pronoun could be **when**, but as this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=every%20time%20when%2C%20every%20time%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cevery%20time%20when%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevery%20time%20that%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cevery%20time%20when%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevery%20time%20that%3B%2Cc0) shows, **that** is used more frequently than **when** after **every time**:

> She gets angry every time **that** I mention it

It is permissible to omit a relative pronoun, thus making two contact clauses, if the relative pronoun is *not* the subject of the relative clause: see [this article](https://englishharmony.com/omitting-relative-pronouns/) for an easy guide for how to tell whether the relative pronoun is the subject.

In your sentence, **I** is the subject of the relative clause, so the relative pronoun can be omitted in informal writing or speech. Your sentence is therefore correct without **when**, but you have done well to spot that something appears to be missing.

It is certainly OK to include the relative pronoun, and I recommend doing so in formal writing. As I mentioned earlier, the preferred relative pronoun would be **that**, rather than **when**.

Comment: If I have understood your message, you need to replace "then" into "when" in this sentence: "Your sentence is therefore correct without then..."

Comment: As I understood you, your message is opposite to Astralbee, isn't it?

Comment: There is no information about "**when**" in the article. There  is only "who/which/that".

Comment: @Sergey, the article is about omission of relative pronouns. In your sentence, **when** would be a relative pronoun. There are no special rules for **when**.

Comment: My answer is not the opposite of Astralbee's: we both agree that **when** can be omitted, but we justify the omission in different ways. My answer is based on logical grammar rules that can be applied to similarly constructed sentences, whereas Astralbee's answer is more... intuitive.

Answer (score -1):

Not gainsaying the answer of "*why the when is missing*" (because of the replacement use of every time). Surely this sentence cannot be left unremarked.

> She gets angry every time I mention it

is this a joke of the ilk of

> You nod your head and I'll hit it

The sentence should be in the form or similar to

> She gets angry every time I mention the subject

Comment: Except there's no possible antecedent for "it" within "She gets angry every time I mention it", unlike the noun "head" in the joke. So "it" obviously refers to something from the missing context.

Comment: Ah! but! There is no context, therefore "it" should not be used in this manner. If there were additional information (context) Then I could agree with you.

Comment: @Brad On ELL, we have to assume that the sentence would occur within a relevant context, but allow that the context is irrelevant to the question. Even it were important, changing **it** to **the subject** does not add any useful context.

Comment: Maybe it does not add useful content but it does teach "you need to consider what you are writing as well as how you are writing it" But there again I personally prefer to teach fishing.